# Sanctum not working with subdomain SPA with vue3

Tags: performance, authentication, subdomain, sanctum

i am using sanctum with multiple subdomain dynamically created on user creation but when I am using test.localhost/project_name subdomain sanctum auth not working but when i am using localhost/project_name its working fine. i have added

SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=umer.localhost:8000,umer.localhost:3000

but no any solution got. if you have any solution please share with me.

Comment: are you solve it ?